# Class Based View and decorators

Tags: python, django-views, python-decorators

I have a FormView for displaying form, and code goes on like this:

```
class AddProject(FormView):
    template_name = "project/add_project.html"

    @method_decorator(check_user_type)
    def dispatch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddProject,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        return AddProjectForm 

    def form_valid(self,form):
        #do validation, return response
```

the decorator check_user_type is like this:

```
def check_user_type(func):
    def wrapped_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['invalid_user'] = True
        return func(request,*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_func
```

In my decorator I want To make sure that only certain type of user get to see the form, i.e if request.user.Iam == 'Architect' or request.user.Iam == 'Interior Designer' only see the form and others see a message "Only architects/Interior Designer get to upload photos".For this i want to insert a variable 'invalid_user' to be passed along, depending on which i display the form or the message.
Problem is I am unable to pass the variable :( alongwith it .. and a doubt.. if i have correctly devised the idea to do so.. ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to pass this argument to `check_user_type` decorator, right? Then you need to nest another function in your decorator, using closure to set variables inside it. Something like

```
def check_user_type(parameter):
    def check_user_type_inner(func):
        def wrapped_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            ... # parameter here depends on argument passed to most outer function
            return func(request,*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
    return check_user_type_inner
```

then parameter is available inside scopes of both inner functions.